# How to start a command from PHP in shell?

Tags: php, unix

When you try to make a commit in git without any message, it will open editor for you right in the shell, and when you will close the editor, git will read the contents.

I want to make exactly the same, but in php.

As I see in git sources ( https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/editor.c ), it just starts process with `use_shell` flag set to true. How can I achieve this in PHP? Also, I see that git sets SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals to ignore. How it can be done in PHP?

Comment: What's the obsession with PHP? Why do you think that PHP is appropriate for this task?

Comment: I'm writing a php command, that's why I want it to work in php, there's no any obsession.

Comment: @nikita2206 There seems like a massive loving for PHP through this question. Other programming languages are available to perform what you have requested

Comment: Here's a context: I have a symfony2 app, it uses postgres for storing data (that's mostly statistical data with complex, postgres-syntax-limited queries). I need to set up a testing environment for acceptance tests... I can't use default postgres instance, cause I need to: have a fully isolated env (without the need for vm) so I can create new database, purge it anytime I (testsuite) want(s), etc., have a fast in-memory database. Here's a small howto on that topic http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/install_multiple_postgresql_servers_redhat_linux/ . But, of course, all this would be PITA for other

Comment: devs to do, that's why I ended up writing script, that could take care of it.

Comment: Of course, this editor thing is not necessary. But it just took my interest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec()` will spawn a process in a shell: http://php.net/shell_exec

To handle signals you'll need to use `pcntl_signal()`, which requires the pcntl extension: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php

A full example, opening a file to edit and then showing the edited contents:

```
$fh = fopen('tmp_file', 'w');
fwrite($fh, "Hello!");
fclose($fh);

shell_exec("nano tmp_file > /dev/tty < /dev/tty");

$data = file_get_contents('tmp_file');
unlink('tmp_file');
echo "You entered: $data\n";
```

You need to redirect input and output to `/dev/tty` to make the process interactive (otherwise it will just hang, depending on the editor).

Comment: Wow, thank you! That's some things that I should definetly learn about *nix shell...